# How I can see value of variable outside subscrib or Promise in Ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm sorry for my english.

I have a problem when trying to see the results of an api rest using subscribe or Promise.

I hava a provider with the next code:

**Provider:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';



@Injectable()
export class UserServiceProvider {

   path : string  = 'my_paht_remote';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello UserServiceProvider Provider');
  }

  getUsers() {

    return this.http.get(this.path');

  }

  getList()
  {
    return new Promise ( resolve => {
      this.http.get(this.path).subscribe(
        data => {

          resolve(data);
        }, err => {
          console.error();
        }

      );


    } );
  }

}
```

**Now, in the file typeScript**:

```
--Imports
...
import { UserServiceProvider } from '../../providers/user-service/user-service';
...
export class CaicesPage {

users: any;
users2: any;
   ...
ionViewDidLoad()
  {
    this.showMap();  //This is a function for see Google Maps. 
  }

showMap()
  {
    //Here I can see the result of JSon File remote:

       this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
        (data) => { // Success
          this.users = data['results'];   



        },
        (error) =>{
          console.error(error);
        }
      );

     console.info(this.users); // I see Undefined, Why ?

   //Whith the next form, Also can see the content File Json
   this.userService.getList().then(

      data => {

        this.users2=data['results'];


      }
    );

    console.info(this.users2); // I see Undefined, Why ?

   }


}
```

How do I can see the values of var users or var users2 outside of subscribe or outsise of THEN ?

I appreciate the collaboration

Answer (score 0):

What do you see if you display the variable in the success branch? Do you see a value then, to confirm that your service is actually returning a correct value? E.g.

```
showMap()
{
//Here I can see the result of JSon File remote:

   this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
    (data) => { // Success
      this.users = data['results'];   
      console.info(this.users); <=============== HERE


    },
    (error) =>{
      console.error(error);
    }
  );
```

You won't see a value with the log in your original position, as this code executes immediately after the call to `subscribe`, i.e. before the service has actually returned a value.

Comment: I see the value of return; Example:  {punto_pago: "Palocabildo-Enertolima", direccion: "CALLE 6 No 6-36 PRIMER PISO CENTRO", tipo_aliado: "Punto de recaudo", horario: "Lunes a viernes de 7:30 am a 12:30 pm y 1:30 pm a 5:00 pm. Sabados 7:30 am a 5:00 pm"}. But, outside subscribe console.info(this.users);  show undefined

Comment: You can only access the value of `this.users` after your successful subscription has executed. In your original code, the sequence of events is: 1. Call getUsers() - an asynchronous call. 2. `console.info(this.users)` - at this point, this.users is still undefined. 3. getUsers() completes and your success subscription executes. Now you can access `this.users`.